# my thumbnail creation using ffmpeg is not working on linux server

Tags: php

I am using ffmpeg in linux server...the video conversion is working fine,but thumbnail creation not working...

here is my code

> exec($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/esebd2/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -i ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/esebd2/".$target_path." -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:10 -an -vcodec png -f rawvideo -s 320×240 ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/esebd2/".$target_pathImg);

i am using codeigniter framework

when i echo the argument for exec i got this Mr.pekka

`/home1/esedirec/public_html/esebd2/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -i /home1/esedirec/public_html/esebd2/cxfolder/george/videos/vid9656326.flv -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:10 -an -vcodec png -f rawvideo -s 320×240 /home1/esedirec/public_html/esebd2/cxfolder/george/thumbs/Img9955639.png`

but the thumbnail not generated

Comment: Please show the full end result of the command line string, with variables replaced, and debug the call using an output variable

Comment: sorry for that,exec(ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -i $target_path -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:10 -an -vcodec png -f rawvideo -s 320×240 target_paththumbnail);

Comment: @shan no, the string with `$target_path` etc. *interpreted* into string data

Comment: it is working fine in windows but not on linux server

Comment: @shan the `ffmpeg` directory contains a linux executable, yes? Not just the Windows .exe?

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server, try to run the command by hand and see what happens. (Make sure you're running it with the web-servers permission, i.e. as user `www-data` or `www`, but this depends on your setup.)

Comment: Yeah, this call definitely needs debugging. There could be any number of things wrong with it (no executable, wrong directory....)

Comment: s pekka ...it has linux exe only because video conversion working fine

Comment: i need answer guys...i am struck in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an actual answer but it will help you debug so run this and let us know what output you get :

```
exec($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/esebd2/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -i ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/esebd2/".$target_path." -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:10 -an -vcodec png -f rawvideo -s 320×240 ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/esebd2/".$target_pathImg, $return, $status);
var_dump($return);
var_dump($status);
```

Comment: I am getting this ----array(0) { } int(1) poelinca

Comment: array(0) means no actual lines where outputed by ffmpeg